# iOS - get wifi user/password from keychain

Tags: keychain

In order to grant quick user authentication, the idea is to use the same credentials of   wifi (enterprise)  network. It is possible to get the user/password used for network access from the app? 
I mean, accessing programmatically to device keychain?

Comment: First of what does this have to do with the `xcode` IDE? Second this is not possible. If it was this would be such a huge security hole as it opens up a can of security worms. I'd definitely rethink your requirements if I was you.

Answer (score 2):

From this [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html)

> iOS: The iOS gives an application access to only its own keychain
>   items.

And I think if developer can access a data as sensitive as a user's wifi password, it can be a serious flaw for the iOS...